What is the best way to merge two lists by markers inside them?
For example, I have two lists:
list1 = ['x', 'x', 'o', 'o', 'x', 'x']
list2 = ['o', 'x', 'o']

I'd like to merge them in a way, that they're aligned by some markers (here it is o), so I'd like to get:
list3 = ['x', 'x', 'o', 'x', 'o', 'x', 'x']

I have only 'x' and 'o' symbols. Two lists ALWAYS have at least one marker, the order of merging two lists does not matter. For instance:
list1 = ['x', 'x', 'o', 'o', 'x', 'x']
list2 = ['x', 'x', 'x', 'o', 'x', 'o']

list3 = ['x', 'x', 'x', 'o', 'x', 'o', 'x', 'x']

What is the best pythonic way to implement it?

What you have tried so far?

Which are the constraints?  E.g. Are the 'o's in the first llist always consecutive? There's only two 'o's in each list? The second list always starts and ends in 'o'?

I tried to play with introducing some global index, but still have no success((

@IgnatiusReilly, both lists always have the same number of 'o', so I'd like to "align" both lists by this symbols

What would be the output if list1 = ['x', 'x', 'o', 'y', 'o', 'x', 'x'] and list2 = ['o', 'x', 'o', 'z']?

@IgnatiusReilly I think it should be '['x', 'x', 'o', 'y', 'x', 'o', 'x', 'x', 'z']', but his question isn't the most clear one as I stated in my answer to this question. I assume that what I did in my answer is what he meant.

@IgnatiusReilly, good question) I have only 'x' and 'o' symbols) I'll add this clarification to my question, thanks!)

@Salt, you're right!)

So items in list1 should appear before items in list2 in the result, when not constrained by the markers? (To explain why x follows y and z follows both final xs.)

@chepner, I've added the edit, that I have only 'x' and 'o' symbols, both lists always have the same number of 'o', two lists always have at least one marker, thank you for your question, I'll also add this to the question)

def merge_lists_by_markers(list1, list2):
    
    l1 = "".join(list1).split("o")
    l2 = "".join(list2).split("o")
    
    l3 = []
    for sublist1, sublist2 in zip(l1, l2):
        if len(sublist1) > len(sublist2):
            l3.append(sublist1)
        else:
            l3.append(sublist2)
            
    return list("o".join(l3))

list1 = ['x', 'x', 'o', 'o', 'x', 'x']
list2 = ['o', 'x', 'o']
list3 = merge_lists_by_markers(list1, list2)
print(list3)

list1 = ['x', 'x', 'o', 'o', 'x', 'x']
list2 = ['x', 'x', 'x', 'o', 'x', 'o']
list3 = merge_lists_by_markers(list1, list2)
print(list3)

Output:
['x', 'x', 'o', 'x', 'o', 'x', 'x']
['x', 'x', 'x', 'o', 'x', 'o', 'x', 'x']

